# showing progress bar while downloading data from multiple database for coredata in ios app

Tags: objective-c, core-data, progress-bar, loading

**Background:**

I have an iPhone app, which needs to download data from multiple tables (at least 10 tables). There are about 80 to 100 rows (each row is about an event) of data in each table. And, there are five separate calls to the web service e.g. getXItems(), getYItems(), getZItems() etc. Once downloaded, it converts them into core-data. All these processes of downloading and converting into core-data is managed by a class: CoredataManager. It takes a while to download, which will frustrate or confuse the users whether the app is broken.

**Question:**

Searching StackOverflow, I have found many solution for implementing a progress bar while downloading files. My questions is, how can I implement a progress bar for the above scenario? The progress bar should take account of the number of the items downloaded in each method call.

Comment: Use NSOperation to download the data or use AFNetworking to download, it provides the progress handler. For core data related stuffs use performBlock to save into database in background.

Comment: Thank you insane-36; I will look into them.